# How to silent install an exe file using perl script

Tags: perl, installation, executable

I want to silent install a software executable file using Perl coding.

I check to have a installer module to run executable file but no luck.

Kindly respond with some idea to initiate .

Comment: It depends if your installer module has a silent mode. If not, this is going to be difficult: you could either unpack the installer and do the install manually, or - and this probably isn't possible on Windows I'd guess - somehow invoke the installer on a virtual desktop and automate the UI.

Comment: That depends entirely on what the installer requires. Does it have a silent mode? Does it open a window and ask for options? Please provide more details.

Comment: for ex : i want to silent install vlc music player using perl script. may i know which module to use and how to automate script to  it.

Answer (score 3):

Would it not make sense to do something like that in a `.bat` or `.ps1` file, using the command:

```
vlc-2.0.1-win32.exe /L=1033 /S
```

(just put the full filepath and executable file in there)?

That should result in a silent install, and looks easier for Windows than trying to use Perl? Or does it have to be Perl for whatever reason?